# Preventing sub-directories to appear in main domain's result

Tags: seo

I have a SaaS site and I want different indexing for my main website and the users on my website. In simpler words, if someone searches for my site(say, www.example.com), results from the user's must not show up in the results. Also, if someone searches exclusively for a customer's website(sub-directory, say www.example.com/username/home/), they should get relevant results according to that, and not my site. How can it be done?

Comment: Are you talking about search engines or a local site search you host?

Answer (score 1):

> If someone searches for my site(say, www.example.com), results from the user's must not show up in the results.

If you want your customer's pages to be indexed as you suggest in your other question, you can't. If you prevent them from being indexed then they can never be shown when a user searches for them.

Just as below, you don't have any real control over what the results of a search result will be. But, if your company name is all over your pages they should tend to rank better then the other pages that do not have it. But there are many factors that affect a page's ranking and some of them may make some of your customer pages rank higher for search results that you want your company to rank for.

But, if you really do want to block anything that is your users' content you can send the a special HTTP header (also available as a meta tag) that will prevent search engines from indexing that content. You would send the `x-robots-tag: noindex` HTTP header with any page you do not want indexed. How you do this will depend on your architecture.

> If someone searches exclusively for a customer's website(sub-directory, say www.example.com/username/home/), they should get relevant results according to that, and not my site. How can it be done?

You have no control over that. But in practical terms, if someone is searching for your customer, their name should be all over their pages. As a result, any queries for them should have a natural bias towards those pages. But there is no guarantee that those page will be shown above others, both outside of your network or within.